# Exibir Interstitial ao clicar no botão home da ToolBar

Tags: android

Tentei implementar a exibição de um banner interstitial no botão home [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] das minhas activitys mas não funcionou corretamente.

Utilizei

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.home){

      if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
          interstitialAd.show();
      }else{
          finish();
      }
   }
}
```

Só que dessa forma o banner não aparece no click e sim apenas ao fechar o app.

Qual e forma correta de exibir o banner ao clicar no botão home?

**QUESTÃO CORRIGIDA E FUNCIONANDO**

*OBs.: A configuração para a exibição do botão home eu fiz direto no manifest, não necessitando setar a toolbar na activity propriamente dita, bastando incluir o código abaixo para pegar a ação no botão home da toolbar.*

**MANIFEST**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MinhaActivitySecundaria"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

**INCLUIR O CÓDIGO ABAIXO NA ACTIVITY SECUNDÁRIA**

*Lembre-se de utilizar a extensão AppCompatActivity*

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == android.R.id.home){

      if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
          interstitialAd.show();
          finish();
      }else{
          finish();
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Henqsan,

Você deve usar o id abaixo que é o id correto para o back button da activity.

```
    if (id == android.R.id.home){
         doSomethink();
    }
```

Lembrando que se você estiver usando Toolbar tem seta-lá.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Eu estou setando o botão back home direto no manifest e estou utilizando  a extensão AppCompatActivity. Portanto, eu não seto a toolbar nas activitys secundárias, apenas na MainActivity.

Comment: mas isto resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu.

Comment: Voltei para retificar o meu comentário feito no post do Ezequiel Messore. Pois além de não me atentar à forma correta de verificar a id `android.R.id.home` eu havia esquecido de chamar o `return true`. Agora está funcionando certinho. Obrigado!